# Add action link from js script

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have js code in view file:

```
function getAuthorData(id) {
    $.get("/web/review/authordata",
        {id: id},
        function (data, status) {
            $(".modal-content #fio").text(data.fio);
            $(".modal-content #email").text("Email: " + data.email);
            $(".modal-content #phone").text("Телефон:" + data.phone);
            $(".modal-content #link").attr("href",
                "<?= Url::toRoute(['/review/getreviewsbyautor']);?>" + "?id=" + id);
        });
}
```

But how ann link to yii2 action from script.js file?

My attempt:

```
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/userData.js');
```

userData.js:

```
function getAuthorData(id) {
    var id2 = id;
    $.get("/web/review/authordata",
        {id: id},
        function (data, status) {
            $(".modal-content #fio").text(data.fio);
            $(".modal-content #phone").text("Телефон:" + data.phone);
            $(".modal-content #link").text("Телефон:" + data.phone);
            $(".modal-content #link").text("href",
                "<?= Url::toRoute(['/review/getreviewsbyautor']);?>" +  id2);
         //   $(".modal-content #link").attr("href", );
        });
}
```

But the link looks like this:

> /web/site/%3C?=%20Url::toRoute([%27review/getreviewsbyautor%27]);?%3E?id=8

How to get a normal route in the script?

Comment: are you talking about pretty urls like `mysite.com/site/index` then you might have to turn on the `urlManager` component settings.

Comment: u can't use php inside js

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the URL in your view and attach it to one of your elements, like the body:

```
<body data-my-url="<?= Url::to(..) ?>">
```

Then read it from your JavaScript file like this:

```
var url = $('body').data('my-url');
```